# Perl regex unable to match using hex or octal

Tags: regex, perl

I need to use Perl to work with a data file that contains a lot of unprintable characters, i.e. not within the displayable character range in the ASCII table.  I tried writing regexes using octal codes for the unprintable characters that I was looking for and could not get them to match.  So next I decided to try using the octal and hex codes for the letter 'e' just to see if my approach was correct or not.  I discovered that even then my code did not work.  Here is a simple sample:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "This is a test string";
print "My string before is \"$string\".\n";

#   The letter 'e' has a position of 101 in the ASCII collating sequence,
#   which is hex '65' and octal 0145.

$string =~ s/0x65//;
print "My string after trying the hex code is \"$string\".\n";

$string =~ s/\0145//;
print "My string after trying the octal code is \"$string\".\n";
```

The output is the following:

```
My string before is "This is a test string".
My string after trying the hex code is "This is a test string".
My string after trying the octal code is "This is a test string".
```

Clearly I am not correctly coding the regex using either the octal or hex notation for the search string, but after doing lots of web searching I haven't been able to find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the solution.  It's described in an article by brian d foy -- https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/10/specify-any-character-by-its-octal-ordinal-value/.  I was indeed incorrectly specifying both the hex code and the octal code.  After finding Brian's article my program is now corrected to be the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "This is a test string";
print "My string before is \"$string\".\n";

#   The letter 'e' has a position of 101 in the ASCII collating sequence,
#   which is hex '65' and octal 0145.

$string =~ s/\x65//;
print "My string after trying the hex code is \"$string\".\n";

$string =~ s/\145//;
print "My string after trying the octal code is \"$string\".\n";
```

With those corrections my program output is now the following:

```
My string before is "This is a test string".
My string after trying the hex code is "This is a tst string".
My string after trying the octal code is "This is a tst string".
```

Thanks, Brian!